# Laravel 5.3 Log some route requests

Tags: php, laravel

I need an opinion in regards to logging some data to my database.

I have the following routes which I have to track:

```
/series/episode/{id}
/movie/{id}
/video/{id}
/music/{id}
```

Each time when there will be a request, a row in database (for each module: series/movie/video/music - separate table) will be inserted with the following data:

- PK - The userid
- PK - The episode/movie/video/music ID
- PK - add_date

I have a large choice to achieve this, but I would like to know which is the most correct way to do so:

1. A middleware
2. Directly inside controller
3. Database Watcher (Query Events)

Don't know which to choose, or maybe there is a specific feature which I don't know about and could prove to be helpful in my particular situation.

What is your opinion?

Comment: I'd go for a middleware.

Comment: @sepehr, the middleware will detect the route and then will do the query depending which module it is?

Comment: One middleware will do. Grab the module name from the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a middleware that is linked to a route. When the route gets triggered, the middleware will go into action. The middleware grabs the id from the URL and creates the log in the database.

This way your controller doesn't expand that much because of code that gets repeated in almost every method.

Comment: Do you think I have to create a middleware for each module (movies/episodes/music/video) or, one common will be better, then detect which is which in middleware?

Comment: Depends how much you want to do in the middleware. If you only want to log I would use one middleware that detecs what to log. If you need to do more, maybe in the future, I would use different middlewares.